# Ms Project VBA Macro Organiser to subproject copy issue

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a simple line of code that attempts to copy text field via project organiser from a Master project/Global.mpt to subproject within the master project (active project). I have tried multiple ways but i'm failing either with
'Run-time error 1101, the file Schedule 1" was not found Or, "This value is not valid in this situation, check the field to see if it requires a text, date or a number, and that you typed the information correctly".
Appreciate your help. Thanks

```
'OrganizerMoveItem Type:=pjFields, FileName:="MASTER SCHEDULE.mpp", ToFileName:=" Schedule1.mpp", 
Name:="Text27"
'OrganizerMoveItem Type:=pjFields, FileName:="C:\xx\MASTER SCHEDULE.mpp", _
'ToFileName:=ActiveProject, Name:="T27(Text27)"
OrganizerMoveItem Type:=9, FileName:="GLOBAL.MPT", _
ToFileName:=ActiveProject.Subprojects("Schedule1.mpp"), Name:="T27"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the subproject file needs to be open in order to use the Organizer to move customizations into it. Viewing the subproject's tasks in the master schedule is not the same as the subproject file being open.

This code will loop through the subprojects and copy the customized Text27 field to each one by opening it, using the Organizer, then closing and saving it.

```
Sub CopyCustomFieldToSubprojects()

Dim master As Project
Set master = ActiveProject

Dim prj As Subproject
For Each prj In master.Subprojects

    FileOpenEx prj.Path
    Projects(prj.SourceProject.Name).Activate
    
    Application.Alerts False
    OrganizerMoveItem Type:=pjFields, FileName:=master.Name _
        , ToFileName:=ActiveProject.Name, Name:="T27 (Text27)"
    Application.Alerts False
    
    FileCloseEx pjSave
    
Next prj

End Sub
```

Note that the [OrganizerMoveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.organizermoveitem) method expects a file name (string) for the FileName and ToFileName parameters rather than a Project object (e.g. `Filename:=master.Name`).

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Rachel to the Rescue again :)